# Unable to copy .xml files in input directory?

Tags: xml, hadoop, directory, mkdir

I have installed hadoop 2.7.1 in ubuntu 15.04. 
I want to copy files from hadoop to input folder that i have made and used the commands :

`$ mkdir input`  (to create the input directory in hadoop_dev)

`$ cp etc/hadoop/*.xml input` ( to copy over all the xml files to input folder)

but it gives the error: `cp: target ‘input’ is not a directory`
Thanks.

Comment: `$ cp etc/hadoop /*.xml input` will probably just copy `etc/hadoop` (is that a file or directory?) to input. `/*.xml` will probably match nothing (did you mean `/etc/hadoop/*.xml`?).

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to copy config files from local filesystem to HDFS, try this:

**1.** Create directory in HDFS:

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir /input
```

**2.** Copy files to HDFS:

```
hdfs dfs -put /etc/hadoop/*.xml /input/
```

**UPDATE 1:**

Export hadoop commands in /home/hadoopuser/.bashrc (exports hdfs command)

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/path/to/hadoop/folder
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
```

Comment: I tried to run "hdfs dfs -mkdir /input"; but it says:          No command 'hdfs' found, did you mean:
 Command 'hfs' from package 'hfsutils-tcltk' (universe)
 Command 'hdfls' from package 'hdf4-tools' (universe)
hdfs: command not found

Comment: Try `$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hdfs dfs -mkdir /input`.

Comment: When I tried "/home/hadoopuser/.bashrc" command.  I think in my case it is "/home/hadoop_dev/.bashrc" -->It says : "-su: /home/hadoop_dev/.bashrc: Permission denied.

Comment: Run the command as `hadoop_dev` user, you wont get permission problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Hadoop File System (FS) shell includes various shell-like commands that directly interact with the Hadoop Distributed File System (HDFS) as well as other file systems that Hadoop supports, such as Local FS, HFTP FS, S3 FS(Amazon), AZURE BLOB(Micorsoft Azure Blob) and others.

Refer hadoop commands [guide](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/CommandsManual.html) which has more information, Im including details about hadoop fs commands that should be used to achieve your requirements, others can be see at referred guide.

```
copyFromLocal

Usage: hadoop fs -copyFromLocal <localsrc> URI

Similar to put command, except that the source is restricted to a local file reference.

Options:

The -f option will overwrite the destination if it already exists.

mkdir

Usage: hadoop fs -mkdir [-p] <paths>

Takes path uri’s as argument and creates directories.

Options:

The -p option behavior is much like Unix mkdir -p, creating parent directories along the path.
Example:

hadoop fs -mkdir /user/hadoop/dir1 /user/hadoop/dir2
hadoop fs -mkdir hdfs://nn1.example.com/user/hadoop/dir hdfs://nn2.example.com/user/hadoop/dir
Exit Code:

Returns 0 on success and -1 on error.
```

Comment: the hadoop folder contains .xml, .xls, .cmd etc files. How to just copy .xml files from "hadoop folder" to move to "input folder".

Comment: hadoop fs -cp /path/*.xml /target/

Comment: It says: " hadoop: command not found" I have installed it in just standalone mode. isn't it the cause that i am getting this error.

Comment: update error log ??  You need to export $HADOOP_HOME

Comment: When I tried "/home/hadoopuser/.bashrc" command. I think in my case it is "/home/hadoop_dev/.bashrc" -->It says : "-su: /home/hadoop_dev/.bashrc: Permission denied.

Comment: nano ~/.bashrc, add the env variable export  $HADOOP_HOME=[path to hadoop home], export $PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$PATH, Save and exit (cntrl+x, then shift+Y, Enter key) then execute source ~/.bashrc.

Comment: The path to hadoop is: 

home/hadoop_dev/hadoop2/etc/hadoop



and to input is:



home/hadoop_dev/input    So what the env variable export $HADOOP_HOME= home/hadoop_dev/hadoop2  or if i am wrong can you interpret "$HADOOP_HOME=[path to hadoop home]" this to me by having info provided above i.e. the paths; as I want to copy .xml files . thanks in advance.